# Bayesian probability: proving $P(x|y,x) = 1$

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have an exercise where I'm supposed to prove that $P(x|y,x) = 1$

I've come up with the following but I'm not sure if it feels right to me:

$P(x|y,x) =$

$P(x,y,x) / P(y,x) = $

$P(x|y,x)P(y|x)P(x) / P(y,x) = $

$P(x|y,x)P(y|x)P(x) / P(y|x)P(x) = $

We now have

$P(x|y,x) = P(x|y,x)$

So:

$P(x|y,x) / P(x|y,x) = P(x|y,x) / P(x|y,x) = 1$

Is this correct?

Comment: You question is not clear. What does $p(x,y,x)$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, it might be an unusual notation used in my class, it means P(x∩y∩x)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $P(x|y,x) = P(x|y \cap x)$, just note that
$$x \cap y \cap x = y \cap x \Rightarrow P(x|y \cap x) = \frac{P(x \cap y \cap x)}{P(y \cap x)} = \frac{P(y \cap x)}{P(y \cap x)} = 1$$

Comment: You assumed right. Thank you